# Compare column value ignoring case - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

My table I feed the data from another database. That source database now changed one column value from `ACTIVE` to `Active`, So my query doesn't return results.

I want to handle this in the query by ignoring the case.

I have the where clause with `IN` function like below.

```
 Select * from myTabble Where mytable.status in ('ACTIVE')
```

Can someone help me to use this query by ignoring case sensitivity. Also I can do one thing. When insert from that source, I can turn the `Active` to `ACTIVE`. I tried that with `upper(sourcedata.status)` in the `Insert` `query` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ignore case, use `UPPER(table.mycolumn) in ('UPPERCASE HERE')`.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `upper(sourcedata.status)` in your insert query, then the rows should be populated with status `ACTIVE`. You could still find `active` only for old record or if you have some other piece of code that is populating that table.

Anyway to stay on the safe side you can use `UPPER` in your select statement:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM myTabble 
 WHERE UPPER(mytable.status) IN ('ACTIVE')
```